# wx.grid.Grid doesn't load image

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

I'm trying to use a code in this [tutorial](http://commentsarelies.blogspot.com/2008/01/simple-wxgridgrid-example.html?m=1), but the result is a grayed cell and no image in the cell (see screenshot). It's been days since I started looking for a solution to add an image to a grid cell and I find this solution the least complicated so far, but it won't work for me. Please, can someone help me with this issue so I can move on with my project? It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
import wx
import wx.grid
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, title = "wx.Grid - Bitmap example")
        grid = wx.grid.Grid(frame)
        grid.CreateGrid(1,1)
        img = wx.Bitmap(r"E:\Dropbox2\Dropbox\Ubot\Ubot\Python\Magnify\Tkinter Magnify\Tests\python-logo.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        imageRenderer = MyImageRenderer(img)
        grid.SetCellRenderer(0,0,imageRenderer)
        grid.SetColSize(0,img.GetWidth()+2)
        grid.SetRowSize(0,img.GetHeight()+2)
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

class MyImageRenderer(wx.grid.PyGridCellRenderer):
    def __init__(self, img):
        wx.grid.PyGridCellRenderer.__init__(self)
        self.img = img
    def Draw(self, grid, attr, dc, rect, row, col, isSelected):

        image = wx.MemoryDC()
        image.SelectObject(self.img)
        dc.SetBackgroundMode(wx.SOLID)
        if isSelected:
            dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.BLUE, wx.SOLID))
            dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLUE, 1, wx.SOLID))
        else:
            dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.WHITE, wx.SOLID))
            dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.WHITE, 1, wx.SOLID))
        dc.DrawRectangleRect(rect)
        width, height = self.img.GetWidth(), self.img.GetHeight()
        if width > rect.width-2:
            width = rect.width-2
        if height > rect.height-2:
                height = rect.height-2
        dc.Blit(rect.x+1, rect.y+1, width, height, image, 0, 0, wx.COPY, True)

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

And the result I get:

[image]

You can use this image for tests:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you are running this in an IDE but if you run it on the command line, you will see all of the warnings and errors. i.e.

```
wxPyDeprecationWarning: Using deprecated class. Use GridCellRenderer instead.
  wx.grid.PyGridCellRenderer.__init__(self)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "20190519.py", line 30, in Draw
    dc.DrawRectangleRect(rect)
AttributeError: 'PaintDC' object has no attribute 'DrawRectangleRect'
```

Acting on these, because the example is old and outdated, we can replace `PyGridCellRenderer` with `GridCellRenderer` and dump the `dc.DrawRectangleRect(rect)` line altogether. if the function doesn't exist, try not using it, then look for an alternative if that doesn't work.

Edit: that line should have been `dc.DrawRectangle(rect)`

We end up with this:

```
import wx
import wx.grid
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, title = "wx.Grid - Bitmap example")
        grid = wx.grid.Grid(frame)
        grid.CreateGrid(2,2)
        img = wx.Bitmap("wxPython.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        imageRenderer = MyImageRenderer(img)
        grid.SetCellRenderer(0,0,imageRenderer)
        grid.SetColSize(0,img.GetWidth()+2)
        grid.SetRowSize(0,img.GetHeight()+2)
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

class MyImageRenderer(wx.grid.GridCellRenderer):
    def __init__(self, img):
        wx.grid.GridCellRenderer.__init__(self)
        self.img = img
    def Draw(self, grid, attr, dc, rect, row, col, isSelected):
        image = wx.MemoryDC()
        image.SelectObject(self.img)
        dc.SetBackgroundMode(wx.SOLID)
        if isSelected:
            dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.BLUE, wx.SOLID))
            dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLUE, 1, wx.SOLID))
        else:
            dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.WHITE, wx.SOLID))
            dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.WHITE, 1, wx.SOLID))
        dc.DrawRectangle(rect)
        width, height = self.img.GetWidth(), self.img.GetHeight()
        if width > rect.width-2:
            width = rect.width-2
        if height > rect.height-2:
            height = rect.height-2
        dc.Blit(rect.x+1, rect.y+1, width, height, image, 0, 0, wx.COPY, True)

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Which gives us this:

[image]

A full set of downloadable documentation is available here: https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.0.4/wxPython-docs-4.0.4.tar.gz
The Demos are here:
https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.0.4/wxPython-demo-4.0.4.tar.gz

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm but I still get this error in the terminal: "NotImplementedError: GridCellRenderer.GetBestSize() is abstract and must be overridden"

Comment: Not sure. I don't get that error. I suppose it might depend on the version you are running. I'm on wx 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

If you got the error as below, then you probably called `setlocale()` directly instead of using `wxLocale`, creating a mismatch between the C/C++ and Windows locales.

Only change the locale by creating `wxLocale` objects to avoid this!

Use these two lines in the code then it will work fine:

```
import locale

#after created the grid

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')
```